# Where is my symbol

Tags: c++, linker, symbols

ALL,

I'm trying to manually compile wxWidgets library - trying to add a new file source to it.

I successfully did compilation:

```
/Users/AlenaKorot/wxWidgets3.0/buildMac/bk-deps g++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -c -o coredll_desktopenvcmn.o -I./.pch/wxprec_coredll -D__WXOSX_COCOA__      -DWXBUILDING -I/Users/AlenaKorot/wxWidgets3.0/buildMac/src/tiff/libtiff -I../src/tiff/libtiff -I../src/jpeg -I../src/png  -I../src/regex  -DWXUSINGDLL -DWXMAKINGDLL_CORE -DwxUSE_BASE=0 -dynamic -fPIC -DPIC -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-deprecated-declarations -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/Users/AlenaKorot/wxWidgets3.0/buildMac/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.0 -I../include -arch i386 -DWX_PRECOMP -ggdb -O0 -arch i386 -fno-common -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden ../src/common/desktopenvcmn.cpp

/Users/AlenaKorot/wxWidgets3.0/buildMac/bk-deps g++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -c -o coredll_osx_cocoa_desktopenv.o -I./.pch/wxprec_coredll -D__WXOSX_COCOA__      -DWXBUILDING -I/Users/AlenaKorot/wxWidgets3.0/buildMac/src/tiff/libtiff -I../src/tiff/libtiff -I../src/jpeg -I../src/png  -I../src/regex  -DWXUSINGDLL -DWXMAKINGDLL_CORE -DwxUSE_BASE=0 -dynamic -fPIC -DPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/Users/AlenaKorot/wxWidgets3.0/buildMac/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.0 -I../include -arch i386 -ggdb -O0 -arch i386 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden ../src/osx/cocoa/desktopenv.mm
```

And linking:

```
g++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -dynamiclib -single_module -headerpad_max_install_names -o /Users/AlenaKorot/wxWidgets3.0/buildMac/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.0.0.3.0.dylib  coredll_desktopenvcmn.o coredll_osx_cocoa_desktopenv.o coredll_event.o coredll_fs_mem.o coredll_msgout.o coredll_utilscmn.o  coredll_osx_cocoa_utils.o coredll_artmac.o coredll_osx_brush.o coredll_dialog_osx.o coredll_osx_fontutil.o coredll_osx_imaglist.o coredll_osx_minifram.o coredll_nonownedwnd_osx.o coredll_osx_palette.o coredll_osx_pen.o coredll_toplevel_osx.o coredll_uiaction_osx.o coredll_utils_osx.o coredll_window_osx.o coredll_core_bitmap.o coredll_core_colour.o coredll_core_dcmemory.o coredll_core_display.o coredll_core_fontenum.o coredll_hid.o coredll_printmac.o coredll_core_timer.o coredll_utilsexc_cf.o coredll_apptraits.o coredll_anybutton_osx.o coredll_bmpbuttn_osx.o coredll_button_osx.o coredll_checkbox_osx.o coredll_checklst_osx.o coredll_choice_osx.o coredll_combobox_osx.o coredll_dnd_osx.o coredll_gauge_osx.o coredll_listbox_osx.o coredll_menu_osx.o coredll_menuitem_osx.o coredll_notebook_osx.o coredll_printdlg_osx.o coredll_radiobox_osx.o coredll_radiobut_osx.o coredll_scrolbar_osx.o coredll_slider_osx.o coredll_spinbutt_osx.o coredll_srchctrl_osx.o coredll_statbox_osx.o coredll_statline_osx.o coredll_stattext_osx.o coredll_textentry_osx.o coredll_textctrl_osx.o coredll_tglbtn_osx.o coredll_toolbar_osx.o coredll_webkit.o coredll_colordlgosx.o coredll_fontdlgosx.o coredll_osx_accel.o coredll_carbon_clipbrd.o coredll_carbon_cursor.o coredll_carbon_fontdlg.o coredll_carbon_gdiobj.o coredll_carbon_icon.o coredll_carbon_app.o coredll_carbon_combobox.o coredll_carbon_control.o coredll_carbon_dataobj.o coredll_carbon_dcclient.o coredll_carbon_dcprint.o coredll_carbon_dcscreen.o coredll_glgrab.o coredll_carbon_graphics.o coredll_carbon_font.o coredll_carbon_frame.o coredll_carbon_mdi.o coredll_carbon_metafile.o coredll_carbon_overlay.o coredll_carbon_popupwin.o coredll_carbon_renderer.o coredll_carbon_settings.o coredll_statbrma.o coredll_carbon_region.o coredll_utilscocoa.o coredll_generic_caret.o coredll_clrpickerg.o coredll_collpaneg.o coredll_colrdlgg.o coredll_dirdlgg.o coredll_generic_fdrepdlg.o coredll_filedlgg.o coredll_filepickerg.o coredll_fontdlgg.o coredll_fontpickerg.o coredll_generic_listctrl.o coredll_prntdlgg.o coredll_generic_statusbr.o coredll_generic_textmeasure.o coredll_cocoa_anybutton.o coredll_osx_cocoa_button.o coredll_osx_cocoa_checkbox.o coredll_osx_cocoa_choice.o coredll_osx_cocoa_colour.o coredll_osx_cocoa_combobox.o coredll_osx_cocoa_dialog.o coredll_osx_cocoa_dirdlg.o coredll_cocoa_dnd.o coredll_osx_cocoa_evtloop.o coredll_osx_cocoa_filedlg.o coredll_osx_cocoa_gauge.o coredll_osx_cocoa_listbox.o coredll_osx_cocoa_menu.o coredll_osx_cocoa_menuitem.o coredll_osx_cocoa_msgdlg.o coredll_cocoa_nonownedwnd.o coredll_osx_cocoa_notebook.o coredll_osx_cocoa_radiobut.o coredll_preferences.o coredll_cocoa_printdlg.o coredll_osx_cocoa_scrolbar.o coredll_osx_cocoa_slider.o coredll_osx_cocoa_spinbutt.o coredll_cocoa_srchctrl.o coredll_osx_cocoa_statbox.o coredll_cocoa_statline.o coredll_osx_cocoa_stattext.o coredll_osx_cocoa_textctrl.o coredll_cocoa_tglbtn.o coredll_osx_cocoa_toolbar.o coredll_osx_cocoa_tooltip.o coredll_osx_cocoa_window.o coredll_accelcmn.o coredll_accesscmn.o coredll_anidecod.o coredll_affinematrix2d.o coredll_appcmn.o coredll_artprov.o coredll_artstd.o coredll_arttango.o coredll_bmpbase.o coredll_bmpbtncmn.o coredll_bookctrl.o coredll_btncmn.o coredll_cairo.o coredll_checkboxcmn.o coredll_checklstcmn.o coredll_choiccmn.o coredll_clipcmn.o coredll_clrpickercmn.o coredll_colourcmn.o coredll_colourdata.o coredll_combocmn.o coredll_cmdproc.o coredll_cmndata.o coredll_containr.o coredll_cshelp.o coredll_ctrlcmn.o coredll_ctrlsub.o coredll_dcbase.o coredll_dcbufcmn.o coredll_dcgraph.o coredll_dcsvg.o coredll_dirctrlcmn.o coredll_dlgcmn.o coredll_dndcmn.o coredll_dobjcmn.o coredll_docmdi.o coredll_docview.o coredll_dpycmn.o coredll_dseldlg.o coredll_effects.o coredll_fddlgcmn.o coredll_filectrlcmn.o coredll_filehistorycmn.o coredll_filepickercmn.o coredll_fontpickercmn.o coredll_fldlgcmn.o coredll_fontcmn.o coredll_fontdata.o coredll_graphicc.o coredll_fontenumcmn.o coredll_fontmap.o coredll_fontutilcmn.o coredll_framecmn.o coredll_gaugecmn.o coredll_gbsizer.o coredll_gdicmn.o coredll_geometry.o coredll_gifdecod.o coredll_graphcmn.o coredll_headercolcmn.o coredll_headerctrlcmn.o coredll_helpbase.o coredll_iconbndl.o coredll_imagall.o coredll_imagbmp.o coredll_image.o coredll_imagfill.o coredll_imaggif.o coredll_imagiff.o coredll_imagjpeg.o coredll_imagpcx.o coredll_imagpng.o coredll_imagpnm.o coredll_imagtga.o coredll_imagtiff.o coredll_imagxpm.o coredll_layout.o coredll_lboxcmn.o coredll_listctrlcmn.o coredll_markupparser.o coredll_matrix.o coredll_menucmn.o coredll_modalhook.o coredll_mousemanager.o coredll_nbkbase.o coredll_overlaycmn.o coredll_ownerdrwcmn.o coredll_paper.o coredll_panelcmn.o coredll_persist.o coredll_pickerbase.o coredll_popupcmn.o coredll_preferencescmn.o coredll_prntbase.o coredll_quantize.o coredll_radiobtncmn.o coredll_radiocmn.o coredll_rearrangectrl.o coredll_rendcmn.o coredll_rgncmn.o coredll_scrolbarcmn.o coredll_settcmn.o coredll_sizer.o coredll_slidercmn.o coredll_spinbtncmn.o coredll_spinctrlcmn.o coredll_srchcmn.o coredll_statbar.o coredll_statbmpcmn.o coredll_statboxcmn.o coredll_statlinecmn.o coredll_stattextcmn.o coredll_stockitem.o coredll_tbarbase.o coredll_textcmn.o coredll_textentrycmn.o coredll_textmeasurecmn.o coredll_toplvcmn.o coredll_treebase.o coredll_uiactioncmn.o coredll_valgen.o coredll_validate.o coredll_valtext.o coredll_valnum.o coredll_wincmn.o coredll_windowid.o coredll_wrapsizer.o coredll_xpmdecod.o coredll_busyinfo.o coredll_buttonbar.o coredll_choicdgg.o coredll_choicbkg.o coredll_combog.o coredll_dcpsg.o coredll_dirctrlg.o coredll_dragimgg.o coredll_filectrlg.o coredll_headerctrlg.o coredll_generic_infobar.o coredll_listbkg.o coredll_logg.o coredll_markuptext.o coredll_msgdlgg.o coredll_numdlgg.o coredll_progdlgg.o coredll_preferencesg.o coredll_printps.o coredll_renderg.o coredll_richmsgdlgg.o coredll_scrlwing.o coredll_selstore.o coredll_spinctlg.o coredll_splitter.o coredll_srchctlg.o coredll_statbmpg.o coredll_stattextg.o coredll_textdlgg.o coredll_tipwin.o coredll_toolbkg.o coredll_treectlg.o coredll_treebkg.o coredll_vlbox.o coredll_vscroll.o coredll_xmlreshandler.o -L/Users/AlenaKorot/wxWidgets3.0/buildMac/lib    -L/Users/AlenaKorot/wxWidgets3.0/buildMac/lib -install_name /usr/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.0.0.dylib   -compatibility_version 4.0 -current_version 4.0 -arch i386 -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework AudioToolbox -framework System -framework OpenGL   -lwxtiff-3.0 -lwxjpeg-3.0 -lwxpng-3.0  -framework WebKit  -lwxregexu-3.0  -arch i386 -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework AudioToolbox -framework System -framework OpenGL  -lz -lpthread -liconv  -lwx_baseu-3.0 -lz -lpthread -liconv
```

Now, here is the strange thing:

```
Alena-Korots-MacBook:buildMac AlenaKorot$ nm -g coredll_osx_cocoa_desktopenv.o | grep -i desktopenv000001ca T __ZN12wxDesktopEnv15MoveFileToTrashERK8wxString
00019dc8 S __ZN12wxDesktopEnv15MoveFileToTrashERK8wxString.eh
00000444 T __ZN12wxDesktopEnv20MoveDirectoryToTrashERK8wxString
00019df8 S __ZN12wxDesktopEnv20MoveDirectoryToTrashERK8wxString.eh
000000aa T __ZN12wxDesktopEnv20MoveFileToRecycleBinERK8wxString
00019c10 S __ZN12wxDesktopEnv20MoveFileToRecycleBinERK8wxString.eh
0000015a T __ZN12wxDesktopEnvC1Ev
00000000 T __ZN12wxDesktopEnvC2Ev
00000070 T __ZN12wxDesktopEnvD0Ev
00000036 T __ZN12wxDesktopEnvD1Ev
00000190 T __ZN12wxDesktopEnvD2Ev
         U __ZN16wxDesktopEnvBase20MoveFileToRecycleBinERK8wxString
0001976c S __ZN16wxDesktopEnvBaseC2Ev
00019ba0 S __ZTI12wxDesktopEnv
         U __ZTI16wxDesktopEnvBase
00019b5a S __ZTS12wxDesktopEnv
00019b88 S __ZTV12wxDesktopEnv
         U __ZTV16wxDesktopEnvBase
```

In the object file there are wxDesktopEnv constructor and wxDesktopEnvBase constructor. However:

```
Alena-Korots-MacBook:lib AlenaKorot$ nm -g  libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.0.dylib | grep -i desktop
Alena-Korots-MacBook:lib AlenaKorot$
```

those symbols are missing from the dylib.

As you can see I'm linking against the appropriate *.o files.

What do I do to fix it? And where my symbols are?

Thank you.

P.S.: Sorry for such a long post with a bit code quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I tried to do the build with mixed directories.

Sorry for the noise.